# Creating a link in linux from root by means of a puppet manifest

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, puppet, foreman

Good afternoon, I need to create a link in the `/usr/share/applications/desktop` Astra Linux directory from the root user. With the name of the link, the path where it leads and the shortcut. How can this be implemented by puppet manifest? I read the documentation and tried, but nothing came out :(.

```
class automount_oep_mount_disk_x {

  # preferred symlink syn
    file { '/usr/share/applications/flydesktop':
    ensure => 'file',
    name +> 'desktop',
  }
```

Comment: Is `+>` a typo? How do you run this, with `puppet apply`?

Answer (score 0):

Whatever documentation you read must not have been the official Puppet Resource Type Reference.  Very near the top of [the docs for the File resource type](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/7/types/file.html), you will find

> The `file` type can manage normal files, directories, and symlinks; **the type should be specified in the `ensure` attribute.**

(Emphasis added)

[The docs for the `ensure` attribute](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/7/types/file.html#file-attribute-ensure) that that references say, in part:

> Possible values are `present`, `absent`, `file`, `directory`, and `link`. [...]
>
> - `link` ensures the file is a symlink, and **requires** that you also set the `target` attribute.

(Emphasis in the original)

As its name suggests, the `target` attribute designates the target of the symlink (I'll spare you yet another excerpt from the docs).

Overall, then, it will look something like this ...

```
file { '/usr/share/applications/flydesktop':
  ensure => 'link',
  target => # you didn't appear say
  # possibly other attributes, too ...
}
```

Of course, this describes only the form of the specific manifest code
for managing the symlink.  The rest of the details of creating classes, classifying nodes, and building and applying catalogs are too many and too diverse for one SO answer.